# How to compare two tables with coordinates and write true of false in column of first table?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have two tables. In one of the coordinates of the cities, and in the other the coordinates of the delivery zones.

How can I compare the coordinates of cities in one of the delivery zones and write 1 or 0 in the column with the names of the zones? If the city at least partially falls into the delivery range, then this should be 1.

I am not very good at programming. I think I need to use code like this:
`boolean && (geometry A, geometry B);`

Or some of this:
`boolean ST_Contains (geometry geomA, geometry geomB);`

But I do not understand [image]how to specify another table. And how to write the results in the column of the table with cities.

Please help with the code!
Thank!

UPD
I need to compare two zones. Is the city zone included in the delivery zone? If it is included or partially included, then specify 1 in the column with the name of the zone. If not included, then 0.
Screen [text exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZPnm.png)

Screen of tables

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: I added a screen of a text file. I have not figured out how to attach text files here. Excuse me.

Comment: what is that text file?

Comment: I need to compare two zones. Is the city zone included in the delivery zone? If it is included or partially included, then specify 1 in the column with the name of the zone. If not included, then 0. I added a screen in the question.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be a query approximately like this:

```
UPDATE cities
   SET green_area = z.ga::integer,
   SET red_area = z.ra::integer
FROM (SELECT place_id,
             bool_or(cities.geom && zones.geom)
                FILTER (WHERE zones.name = 'green_area') AS ga,
             bool_or(cities.geom && zones.geom)
                FILTER (WHERE zones.name = 'red_area') AS ra
      FROM zones
         JOIN cities ON cities.geom && zones.geom
      GROUP BY cities.place_id
     ) AS z
WHERE cities.place_id = z.place_id;
```

`&&` is the “overlaps” operator for geometries.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE cities
   SET  green_area = z.ga::integer,
        red_area = z.ra::integer
FROM (SELECT place_id,
             bool_or(cities.geom && zones.geom)
                FILTER (WHERE zones.name = 'green_area') AS ga,
             bool_or(cities.geom && zones.geom)
                FILTER (WHERE zones.name = 'red_area') AS ra
      FROM zones
         JOIN cities ON cities.geom && zones.geom
      GROUP BY cities.place_id
     ) AS z
WHERE cities.place_id = z.place_id;
```

Yes! This code work for me perfectly!
Biggest thx to [Laurenz Albe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57766202/7202492)! You are awesome!))